# Finding an equation for t in terms of several variables.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been stuck on this question from Isaac Physics for a long time. There are four equations and I must find an equation for $t$ in terms of $X$, $T$, $v$, $c$ and $γ$. Here are the four equations:

$$X=γ(x-vt)$$
$$T=γ(t-\frac{vx}{c^2})$$
$$γ^2=\frac{1}{1-(v^2/c^2)}$$
$$x=Tvγ+γX$$

I first substituted the last equation into the second equation to get:
$$T=γ(t-\frac{v(Tvγ+γX)}{c^2})$$
which I then expanded:
$$T=γt-\frac{γv(Tvγ+γX)}{c^2}$$

I subtracted $γt$ and $T$ from both sides:
$$-γt=-T-\frac{γv(Tvγ+γX)}{c^2}$$

Then, I divided both sides by $-γ$:
$$t=\frac{T}{γ}+\frac{v(Tvγ+γX)}{c^2}$$

The result is an equation for $t$ in terms of $X$, $T$, $v$, $c$ and $γ$, which is what the question wanted. However, this answer is marked incorrect so I am not sure where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Solve the first equation for $t$ in terms of $X, x, v, \gamma$ and substitute in the fourth. Maybe you could post the desired expression?

Comment: But this does not involve $c$?

Comment: I'm not sure what the desired expression is because I can't see the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Note that your four equations are redundant. For instance, the last one, $vT+X=\frac x\gamma$, can be derived from the three first ones:
  $$vT+X=vγ\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)+γ\left(x-vt\right)=γx\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)=\frac xγ.$$
- Your answer is correct, but there are infinitely many correct answers, due to the third equation. You can use it to transform your answer, e.g., into:
  $$t=\gamma\left(T+\frac{vX}{c^2}\right).$$
- Another correct answer can also be derived from the sole two first equations, by eliminating $x$ between them:
  $$\frac X\gamma+vt=x=\frac{c^2}v\left(t-\frac T\gamma\right)$$
  $$\implies t\left(\frac{c^2}v-v\right)=\frac X\gamma+\frac{c^2T}{v\gamma}$$
  $$\implies t=\frac{T+\frac{vX}{c^2}}{γ\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)}.$$

Comment: This makes sense. It turns out that the 'correct' answer was $t=γ(T+\frac{vX}{c^2})$. I suppose they wanted an equation with only one occurrence of each variable...

Comment: When I submit an answer, it only says whether it is correct or incorrect, with no further explanation. So when I entered the above equation, it said it was correct, and therefore it is confirmed that this is the 'correct' answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! I did not know "Isaac Physics", I thought it was a textbook.

Comment: No worries, I probably should have made it clearer.